# Check if array is ASCII

Tags: c, arrays, ascii

How do I check in C if an array of uint8 contains only ASCII elements?
If possible please refer me to the condition that checks if an element is ASCII or not

Comment: What type is your array? Worth including as much information as you can in the question text

Comment: Use a [`for loop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) and use one of [these](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) functions, depending on what you want to know.

Comment: And those functions require that the argument is an unsigned char

Comment: forgot to mention it @Seb . its uint8

Comment: @hellow   I was thinking of using a for loop to parse the array but I'm pretty sure those function won't work with uint8

Comment: @wialex2501 Are you sure you're interested in whether they're ascii, or are you interested if they're printable characters?

Comment: @Seb im only interested in checking if the reffered bytes are in ascii format

Comment: @wialex2501 re, the ctype.h functions, they will work.  There will be an implicit cast from `uint8` to `int` (or you supply an explicit cast), but presumably `uint8` is simply an alias for `unsigned char`?  The behaviour of these functions is undefined if the value is not representable as `unsigned char` - they may generate positive result for characters in the range 128-255, so strictly for ASCII you need to also test the range <= 127 (or `(ch & 0x3f) == 0`).

Comment: "Checking if the referred bytes are in ASCII format": You have to ask the person that created the bytes or consult relevant standards, documentation, … that describes the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array elements are uint8, so must be in the range 0-255

For standard ASCII character set, bytes 0-127 are used, so you can use a for loop to iterate through the array, checking if each element is <= 127.

If you're treating the array as a string, be aware of the 0 byte (null character), which marks the end of the string

From your example comment, this could be implemented like this:

```
int checkAscii (uint8 *array) {
    for (int i=0; i<LEN; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 127) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It breaks out early at the first element greater than 127.

Comment: uint8 means unsigned 8 bit integer; char is usually the same thing, and "byte" is a bit of a generalisation for "8 bits of memory storage"; so as long as the type of your array values a single-byte unsigned, you can generally treat them the same

Comment: so something like this should work?
    uint8 asciiCheck(uint8 *array){
 uint8 i=(uint8)0,ok=(uint8)1;
 for(i=(uint8)0;(ok==(uint8)1)&&(i<LEN);i++){  
  if(array[i]<=0||array[i]>=127){
   ok=(uint8)0;
  }
  return ok;
 }
}

Comment: sorry for bad formatting of the code.Also i just realized that "return ok" should be before the last bracket. @Seb

Comment: @wialex2501 added an example for you

Comment: Disagree in detail about: "uint8 means unsigned 8 bit integer; char is usually the same thing".  Many systems, if not most, treat `char` as a _signed_ 8-bit type - as allowed by C.

Answer (score 3):

All valid ASCII characters have value 0 to 127, so the test is simply a value check or 7-bit mask.  For example given the inclusion of stdbool.h:

```
bool is_ascii = (ch & ~0x7f) == 0 ;
```

Possibly however you intended only printable ASCII characters (excluding control characters).  In that case, given inclusion of ctype.h:

```
bool is_printable_ascii = (ch & ~0x7f) == 0 && 
                          (isprint() || isspace()) ;
```

Your intent may be lightly different in terms of what characters you intend to include in your set - in which case other functions in [ctype.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/) may be applied or simply test the values for value or range to include/exclude.

Note also that the ASCII set is very restricted in international terms. The ANSI or "extended ASCII" set uses locale specific codepages to define the glyphs associated with codes 128 to 255.  That is to say the set changes depending on language/locale settings to accommodate different language characters, accents and alphabets. In modern systems it is common instead to use a multi-byte Unicode encoding (or which there are several with either fixed or variable length codes).  [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding is a variable width encoding where all single byte encodings are also ASCII codes.  As such, while it is trivial to determine whether data is entirely within the ASCII set, it does not follow that the data is therefore *text*.  If the test is intended to distinguish binary data from text, it will fail in a great many scenarios unless you can guarantee *a priori* that all text is restricted to the ASCII set - and that is application specific.

Comment: Does this still apply for bytes as well?

Comment: @wialex2501: Please understand that `'byte'` is not a data type in C, so when you say byte, others may conveniently assume is to be a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @WedaPashi Byte is however a well-defined term in C. Namely, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 byte. A `char` is always 1 byte, a `uint8_t` is always 1 byte. In the rare case where a byte is not 8 bits, `uint8_t` will not be supported.

Comment: @wialex2501 : It does not matter what the integer type is so long as it is at least 7 bits wide.  In most cases you would hold ASCII text in a `char` array which is _almost_ universally 8 bits wide (i.e. a "byte").  Of course it is possible to have _binary_ data whose values happen to also be valid ASCII characters - after all half of all 8 bit values match ASCII values.

Comment: There is no easy way of determining whether an array contains human readable text; it would require some rudimentary heuristic assessment at least - such as space separated groups containing a reasonable frequency of vowels, or groups matching a dictionary for example.

Comment: @Clifford: Totally agree, I just put up that comment just to make sure that the OP does not confuse a lot when he/she talk about 'bytes'. Because, 'bytes' together can form a `float` as well, but ASCII has got nothing to do with it.

Comment: `ch & 0x7F` only checks if bits 0 to 127 are set. The logic is flawed, `0x81 & 0x7F` is 1. It should be `(ch&0x7f)==ch`.

Comment: @Lundin - copy & paste error.  Fixed - thanks for the spot.  Although I went with `(ch&0x7f) == 0` (all bits >b7 are zero). Same effect, but single evaluation of `ch`.

Comment: No, you messed up again :) If bits 0 to 7 are all zero, then it is either the value `'\0'` or an extended symbol table, either is not printable.

Comment: @Lundin :  I see your point - still a copy an paste error, adapting the first fragment from the second omitting to change the variable name to something sensible.  The intent in the first fragment was ASCII, not printable ASCII.

Comment: @Lundin : next time I am being dense; just fix it for me! ;-) - `(ch & ~0x7f) == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check if something is "ASCII" with standard C.

Because C does not specify which symbol table that is used by a compiler. Various other more or less exotic symbol tables exists/existed.

UTF8 for example, is a superset of ASCII. Older, dysfunctional 8 bit symbol tables have existed, such as EBCDIC and "Extended ASCII". To tell if something is for example ASCII or EBCDIC can't be done trivially, without a long line of value checks.

With standard C, you can only do the following:

- You can check if a character is printable, with the function `isprint()` from ctype.h.
- Or you can check if it only has up to 7 bits only set, `if((ch & 0x7F)==ch)`.

Comment: Noting that `isprint()` does not include whitespace, and that `isspace()` includes little used codes such as "vertical tab".

Comment: Also iirc there was an old non-standard function `isascii` in DOS and UNIX, which simply did check if something fit in 7 bits.

Answer (score 1):

In C programming, a character variable holds ASCII value (an integer number between 0 and 127) rather than that character itself.

The ASCII value of lowercase alphabets are from 97 to 122. And, the ASCII value of uppercase alphabets are from 65 to 90.

incase of giving the actual code , i am giving you example.

**You can assign int to char directly.**

```
int a = 47;
char c = a;
printf("%c", c);
```

And this will also work.

```
printf("%c", a);  // a is in valid range
```

**Another approach.**

An integer can be assigned directly to a character. A character is different mostly just because how it is interpreted and used.

```
char c = atoi("47");
```

Try to implement this after understand the following logic properly.